# What is the hlsl `dst` instruction for?

Tags: hlsl

The [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219790%28VS.85%29.aspx) say `dst` "Calculates a distance vector" by:

```
dest = dst( src0, src1 ) ;
```

It says,

> The first source operand (src0) is assumed to be the vector (ignored, d*d, d*d, ignored) and the second source operand (src1) is assumed to be the vector (ignored, 1/d, ignored, 1/d). The destination (dest) is the result vector (1, d, d*d, 1/d).

```
//Code
dest.x = 1;
dest.y = src0.y * src1.y;
dest.z = src0.z;
dest.w = src1.w;
```

What is the meaning of this really?  Why would you want to use it?

Comment: http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/graphics-programming-and-theory/shader-programming-part-i-fundamentals-of-vert-r1496

Answer (score 0):

In computer graphics, it is a very common job to compute the length of a vector - e.g. to compute the distance between two points. Given that you have already computed the difference between the points, the distance can be computed as:

```
d = sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);
```

Unfortunately, computing the root of a number is very expensive; as a matter of fact, the fastest method currently known is to first compute the *inverse* of the root, and from that compute the root itself, like so:

```
// invsqrt(x) := 1/sqrt(x)

dSqr = x*x + y*y + z*z;
dInv = invsqrt(d);
d = 1/dInv;
```

Note that the last line can be replaced by:

```
d = dSqr*dInv;
```

and in practice this may indeed be a tad more efficient, as division again tends to be more expensive than multiplication.

Now, more often than not, portions of the "downstream" code operating on the distance may need to operate not on `d` itself, but rather on `d*d` (e.g. plugging it into further pythagoras-ish computations), or `1/d` (e.g. in fog-ish shaders), or even `1/(d*d)` (e.g. in lighting computations).

Such computations can be optimized away, or at least implemented more efficiently, by passing to the downstream code not only our final result, but also our interim values; thus, you might decide to pass an entire batch of distance-based values - which is probably what Microsoft means by "distance vector":

```
d
d*d
1/d
```

Now as for why there's also a `1` in that vector I'm not sure, but it results in the neat property that the vector contains the complete set of integer powers of `d` from `pow(d,-1)` through `pow(d,2)` (albeit swizzled around a bit)

The `dst` instruction appears to be designed to perform the final step in assembling such a distance vector: After you have first computed the distance's square in one register, and then from that the distance's inverse in another register, the `dst` instruction will throw those values together into a single register, computing a product along the way to compute the actual distance.

As for why the input registers need to "present" the input operands in multiple components each, I guess this is so that the microcode implementing the instruction can be optimized (and actually this might be the true reason for having the `1` in there): Notice how the `dst` operation is effectively a component-wise multiplication of the two operands, except that each source operand has two of its components replaced by a `1`:

```
dest = (1, src0.y, src0.z, 1) * (1, src1.y, 1, src1.w);
```

So there: That's how the `dst` instruction could be useful when dealing with distances, what Microsoft might mean by "distance vector", and where some of the instruction's oddities might have their roots (pun intended).